# Static vs Instance in Parallel Loop which is better in terms of memory and performace

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization

I wanted to know what is a better approach for solving the below problem. 
I have a situation where I will be making a service call and db call and based on the inputs  i will be doing some calculations and return some mismatch between those two.

I have the below sample snippet: If anyone could advise if making the Class static is better or the instance method is better as the call will be from Parallel.for where multiple threads will be using it at the same time.

```
    //Sample Call ..actually will be controllig no of parallel calls using MAxDegreeofparallelism
    Parallel.For(1, 10, i =>
        {
            SomeClass c = new SomeClass();
            var res=c.SomeMethod("test", "test");
        });
    public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly IDbRepositroy _IDbRepository =null;
    private readonly IServiceRepositroy _IServiceRepositroy = null;
    public  SomeClass()
    {
        _IDbRepository = new DbRepository(); // Can do DI 
        _IServiceRepositroy = new ServiceRepositroy(); // Can DO DI

    }

    //Here Return Type is shown as string but can a new class object of errors
    public List<Errors> SomeMethod(string param1,string param2)
    { var err = new List<Errors>();
        var dbData = _IDbRepository.GetDbData(param1, param2);
        var serviceData = _IServiceRepositroy.GetServiceData(param1, param2);

        //Based on Servcie Data and DB data Calculate erros and return
        //Code Logic
        //Multiple Logic
        return err;


    }
}
```

Comment: If it is only a matter of a few threads, go for the solution that makes you code simple/readable/understandable. Using async/Task instead of Parallel is also preferable.

Comment: We will be making around 100 thousand calls to this... But 32-50 threads in parallel... I was looking answers more on the no of object created in when class is non static and when we use static class.. How performance or memory will be better

Comment: If we are talking 32-50 i would not use Parallel or any other kind of threads, i would distribute the "jobs" over the network instead. How many cores (vitual) do you have on the machine?

Comment: But still a single static method don't gain much performance, if you create many objects inside it. It is more important that what ever is running within the threads, they are using async and Task.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion... But the thing is we cannot change the pattern rt now as we already have the architecture in place and in that parallel call we already have other things running I have to add one more... So on that front how should I proceed with creating the class instance where multiple threads will have their own instance or one single static class...

Comment: And if I choose to. Ake the class static will the private reository instance which will be static also... Do any harm to my data... Like data corruption..

Comment: If you make the class and method static, all threads will use the same repository instances. Therefore, they must be thread-safe.

Comment: If you model/architecture is not prepared for threading using static, then don't. Threads share state on static, so you have to do locking. Let each thread have it own state by not using static - and you have avoided lots of debugging and headaches. Since you are calling database and stuff, going static will not gain much performance anyway.

Comment: Thanks.. I asked the question of static as my class does not seem to have any state.Also in the place where I have put logic more logic... I can use utility static methods which will take some input and give back output... That should not create any issues rt..

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I mean as suggested by most of you if I make SomeClass as static then the repository instances may run into issues. So il be keeping Someclass as non static. But wanted to know for data manipulation can I create a utility method inside SomeMethod and use it without any fear of data being mixed and yeah if it has anything to do with performance

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it make sense to prepare a cache providing some set of class instances and get instance from cache when required. It is better to avoid creating new class instances during execution of parallel operations because it may cause specific GC operations that may block all running threads (mostly they run in a single thread, but if they block application this is an issue). BTW: The best way to check what is going one is to use some profile tools. I prefer PerfView provided by Microsoft, since it help to diagnose problems with GC.